# Collocations for "level" to describe the seriousness of something

Tags: word-request, collocations

Consider:

> These days, Tehran's air pollution is at a risk level.

What are different levels of the seriousness of something? For example can we say "warning level"?

Comment: There are no *set* levels it depends on context, but often "low"/"medium"/"high" gets used.

Comment: These are arbitrary designations established by governmental and non-governmental bodies.  The government has them for states of emergency, the environmental organizations have them for air quality and endangered species, to reflect degrees of endangerment, etc etc.

Comment: @TRomano yes, but to know some labels is useful, and to know which labels can work. For example I doubt if we can say "warning level", can we?

Comment: You're not asking about the English language per se but about cultural and societal conventions here. There's nothing grammatically amiss with "warning level".

Comment: @TRomano I first asked the levels in general, then I thought I should ask it more specifically. It seems I should edit it back to a general question. In general there should be some general levels, like "moderate", "safe", "alarm", "warning"...anyway!

Comment: Yes, you should stop using such specific titles. What does the grammatical question have to do with air pollution? "Different levels of seriousness of air pollution"

Comment: **warning** and **alarm** are  not the same kind of adjective as **moderate** and **severe**. You're mixing fish and fowl.

Comment: @TRomano In general, forget "air pollution". I look for some collocations for "level" that work. I got some "safe", "emergency", ...

Comment: @TRomano then you admit "alarm" and "warning" are idiomatic too.

Comment: No, I do not, not when you're trying to find words for a gradient, if said gradient already has been labeled with  "moderate" and "severe". For such a purpose, you need *words which have true opposites*.  What is the opposite of "warning" and "alarm"???

Comment: You would want an adjective - "alarming level", "risky level". "Warning" as an adjective means something that warns you, like a warning sign, not something that worries you like high pollution levels.

Comment: @tromano right, however I expected an answer like the one from ColleenV about the word usages. Please note that I'm a learner and can't be sure a combination is idiomatic or not.

Answer (score 1):

The term  you might be looking for is Air Quality Index, given as a number and a description for the health risks associated with them. Different countries have their own index. What you say will depend on which index you find useful as regards Iran. Some might be: health risk level, high risk level, etc.

You can check out the numbers and the lingo used for the AQIs and the linguistic descriptions of them here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_quality_index

Generally speaking, an index has levels. So, you can say: health risk level, health threat level, etc. Usually, the word health is used in association with some other term.